# In Xcode, is it possible to reuse intermedian objects from i386 configuration where building with universal configuration?

Tags: xcode, macos, universal

My application should be built as both of x86 and universal(x86 & x86_64) versions. As a result, every source file, says file A, must be compiled three times:

1. As i386, when building with the x86 configuration
2. As i386, when building with universal configuration
3. As x86, when building with universal configuration

Since A has already be compiled as i386 when building with x86 configuration, could the universal configuration reuses objects from x86 configuration?

I found the intermedian objects resided under simliar path: Objects-normal/{i386,x86_64}. So could I set the intermedian object path of both configurations into a same path? So that, the universal building could reuse objects from x86 build?

I have not tried it, and just want to known whether anyone has tried this before?

Comment: Why on earth do you need to do that? You know that the universal app runs on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines, right? Is it something your employer told you to do?

Comment: Yuji, you are insightful. I know what is Universal, and be told to build 32-bit and 64-bit separately. But, we have to do this because of some issues in our integrating/building system. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build the universal version and then if you really need an i386-only version as well you can add a post build step which uses `lipo` to generate the "thin" version of the executable.